# What is this kind of number and how to conver it? 1.1480996566692E+14

Tags: php, variables, curl

I'm using `CURL` and from some URL I'm getting *Account ID* like "**1.1480996566692E+14**". I know this must be an integer. But I don't know how to convert it into human readable formate.
Can someone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Scientific Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) - It is an actual number; but tell whoever runs that API to fix it to a full integer/string output

Comment: Actually i have to use it in mysql query with varchar field

Comment: Use `sprintf()` to fix its format (`$value = 1.1480996566692E+14;
$value = sprintf('%d', $value);
var_dump($value);`)... but there's a strong possibility that the API is causing loss of precision (least significant digit) by using scientific notation, so get them to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a double value, just use floatval to transform string to double value.`

```
$number="1.1480996566692E+14";
$doublevalue=floatval($number);
echo sprintf("%.0f",$doublevalue);
```

Comment: I got this one "114809965666923.000000" which is correct. But i don't want .000000. Can you give me a solution.

Comment: yes, change to echo sprintf("%.0f",$doublevalue); coded edited

Answer (score 0):

that would be `1.1480996566692E+14 = 1.1480996566692 * (10 ^14)` or `(int) 1.1480996566692E+14`

Comment: Getting some integer value but not getting the actual value.